How do I install wine on my raspbian os pi 4 using git cloning?
I am using the general code for downloading git clones to rasbian, git clone https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine, but after i set cd to wine and enter '''make''', it says "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop." Help!

did you follow the instructions?

wine is available through apt...  do you have something against apt?

@Seamus Perhaps Wine version 8 is too old for OP
